# Insert two column values into single SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

The following two tables `Table 1` and `Table 2` are given-

`Table 1
+-----+------+---------+
| ID  | Name | Earning |
+-----+------+---------+
| 101 | John | HRA     |
| 101 | John | Travel  |
| 102 | Andy | Travel  |
+-----+------+---------+`

`Table 2
+-----+------+---------+
| ID  | Name |Deduction|
+-----+------+---------+
| 101 | John | ENP     |
| 102 | Andy | ENP     |
| 102 | Andy | RA      |
+-----+------+---------+`

and I need to create a third table `Table 3` with following columns 
I have already created two columns `ID` and `Name` .I only need `EarningOrDeduction` column.

With

`INSERT INTO Table3 (ID, Name, EarningOrDeduction)
SELECT ID, Name, Earning FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Name, Deduction FROM Table2;`

I'm getting

`Table 3
+-----+------+------------------+
| ID  | Name |EarningOrDeduction|
+-----+------+------------------+
| 101 | John | HRA              |
| 101 | John | Travel           |
| 102 | Andy | Travel           |
| 101 | John | ENP              |
| 102 | Andy | ENP              |
| 102 | Andy | RA               |
+-----+------+------------------+`

But I want output as

`Table 3
+-----+------+------------------+
| ID  | Name |EarningOrDeduction|
+-----+------+------------------+
| 101 | John | HRA              |
| 101 | John | Travel           |
| 101 | John | ENP              |
| 102 | Andy | Travel           |
| 102 | Andy | ENP              |
| 102 | Andy | RA               |
+-----+------+------------------+`

Comment: Is `HRA, Travel` one value or 2 here?

Comment: Two different values

Comment: Please add example input and output.

Answer (score 0):

You could try inserting a union of values from the two tables:

```
INSERT INTO Table3 (ID, Name, EarningOrDeduction)
SELECT ID, Name, Earning FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Name, Deduction FROM Table2;
```

Or, if you don't really want to populate `Table3` with these values, you could just run the above select without the first insert line.

Comment: To the OP, if this table is just a selection of these values, I would use a `VIEW` instead. Replace Tim's `INSERT INTO...` line with `CREATE VIEW [ViewName] AS...`. This'll mean you aren't storing the values elsewhere, and also you won't have to update `Table3` every time a value in `Table1` or `Table2` is updated or inserted..

Comment: Sorry for not being clear in my question.What I need is to also pass a parameter where `Table3` gets data by matching the `ID` column from both `table 1` and `table 2` with it's own.

Comment: @RahulThakur Then edit your question and show us the actual problem.  From both answers, it is clear that your intended question did not come across.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've edited my question with tables for better understanding

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen please check my question again.I'm unable to get the desired output.

Comment: My query should be giving the correct output.  Perhaps your data is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can select both table data with **Union** clause.
And if you don't want to insert already entered values use following query.

```
INSERT INTO Table3 (EarningOrDeduction)
SELECT X FROM(
SELECT Earning X FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT Deduction X FROM Table2
    ) T
LEFT JOIN Table3 T3 ON T.X=T3.EarningOrDeduction
WHERE T3.EarningOrDeduction IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

UNION ALL with Order by should work.

```
INSERT INTO Table3 (ID, Name, EarningOrDeduction)
SELECT ID, Name, EarningOrDeduction from 
(SELECT ID, Name, Earning as [EarningOrDeduction] FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Name, Deduction FROM Table2) ORDER BY ID, Name;
```

I assume Earnings and Deduction will not produce duplicate value for particular Name.